# I cannot open Anaconda and Jupyter has 0 active kernels

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

Firstly, I re-installed Anaconda, but I cannot open Anaconda. When I click it, it has no response. When I am trying to open Anaconda at the command line using the following:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

I got an error as follows:

```
from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
```

But I actually have piped pyqt5. I do not know how to solve it, I cannot open Anaconda.

Secondly，as I am not able to open Anaconda, I am trying to open Jupyter at the command line using `jupyter notebook`, but I got error as `0 active kernels`. When I get into the Jupyter notebook, I can't do anything. I cannot build a new file as follows: when I click the new button, no response.

[image]

I've tried to re-install Python and Anaconda many times, but I still get the error. Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong with it?

Comment: can you give us more details on your setup, operating system, environment, installation procedure and potential errors along the way, versions of python, conda you are using etc... This is currently too broad to give any specific answer...